# Will Anaconda work well if it is not the system python?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10

I want to install Anaconda so I can use it to work with TensorFlow and similar packages but there is a problem. I use Python 3.8 for all my other projects and the version of Python that Anaconda uses is 3.7. Now, I got a question if I want to set that Anaconda's Python as a system one which I do not want. Is it okay to just uncheck that box or should I do something more? I am working on Windows 10 btw.

Comment: yes, anaconda will work fine if it is not system python, bc the anaconda is in another env,

Comment: Anaconda will install its own python with its own dependencies separated from the system's ones. There should be no problem.

Comment: I'll go with it then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will but you should use virtual environments. Use the cond command to creat you virtual environment and to define the version of python to use. An example command to create a virtual environment is:

```
conda create -n your_env_name python=3.7 anaconda
```

Then just activate this environment before running. You only have to create a virtual environment once.